# EF Core using navigation property when querying parent and child separatedly

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm currently developing something with EF Core and I'm not yet fluent in linq-to-Entity or in linq for that matter.

I have two entities that I need to query, one is the customer and the other are the invoices. But I need to retrieve only his/her latest invoice, and I only need customers that have been active (aka made a purchase) in the last x days.

I'd like to do the following to obtain the customers

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = _context.Customers
           .Where(c => c.LastUpdate > date)
           .ToList();
```

And this to obtain the invoices

```
IEnumerable<Invoice> invoices = _context.Invoices
           .Where(i => customers.Contains(i.customerId)).ToDictionary(i => i.customerId, i => i)
           .Where(c => c.Invoices.Max(i => i.Date) = i.Date) //I don't know how to do this part but I hope you get the idea that I'm trying to get only the newest invoice for each customer
           .ToList();
```

The question is whether or not I'll be able to use the Invoice.Customer property find the customer this invoice belongs to, or alternatively Customer.Invoice.First() to get the corresponding invoice.

Or is there another way to do this? Sorry I'm a noob and usually I work more with sql, but I'm trying to move with the times...

Btw I'd like to keep this with the entity framework syntax only and rather not deal with linq and IQueryable because I'm trying to deal only with entities and wouldn't like to map things in the repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `IQueryable<T>` instead of the `IEnumerable<T>` when using an ORM like EF. The `IQueryable<T>` instructs the compiler to create an expression tree (`Expression<T>`) which is traversed by the query engine in the ORM to generate an optimized SQL statement for the underlying DB.  The `IEnumerable<T>`, however, is complied (not an expression tree) and only the CLR can understand which means the query engine has lost the visibility into LINQ-to-Entity.

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = context.Customers.Where(x => x.State=="CA")
```

translates to:

```
Select * from Customers
```

Instead of the RDBMS doing the work, the ORM will retrieve the entire customer table and have the CLR enumerate the collection to find all customers who live in California which is highly inefficient.

```
IQueryable<Customer> customers = context.Customers.Where(x => x.State=="CA")
```

translates to:

```
Select * from Customers Where State='CA'
```

The `Invoice` entity class should have the `Customer` as a navigation property. This allows you to get the customers who are active in the x days and their latest invoice.

** **UPDATE** **

```
var results = context.Invoice
    .Where(x => x.Customer.LastUpdate > 'DateTime')
    .GroupBy(c => c.Customer.Id)
    .Select(grp => new {
          Cust = grp.Key, 
          LatestInvoice = grp.OrderByDescending(inv => inv.InvoiceDate).First()
       })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! but there's something that is not very clear to me, where are you telling the context the list of customerIds? in the line with ```var results =…```
Btw, it seems that my example wasn't very clear but the table ```customers``` has a field ```lastUpdate``` which has the last date they purchased something, but this isn't necessarily the same date of the invoice, because the invoice is generated at a later date when their order is ready for shipping. So, ```customer.lastUpdate != invoice.date```

Comment: Sounds like you need to normalize your tables.  The `Customer` table should only have data pertaining to the customer entity like id, Name, address, email, phone number, etc.  The last purchase date should be part of the `Order` or `Invoice` table.  Generally speaking, tables have `InsertDate` and `LastUpdateDate` columns to denote when the record was inserted and updated.

Comment: well, maybe but that part of the design wasn't my choice and it is not under my control. I also forgot to mention that I do indeed have a navigation property called customer in invoice. And that it is not a requirement to do this as a 2 step, I could also do it in one go if I knew how. But the doubt regarding your answer still persist, where are you telling the invoices the customerIds that I'd filter from the first step you mentioned

Comment: You should have `CustomerId` as a foreign key in the `Invoice` table.  That relationship and your entity mapping tell EF how to join the `Customer` and `Invoice` tables based on `Customer.Id`.  That's how I was able to ask the context to group the records based on the customer.id and select the latest invoice from that grouping.

Comment: there is indeed a ```CustomerId``` foreign key in the ```invoice table```. Like I mentioned there is a navigation property that indeed translated into said foreign key. I just don't understand in the example you provided in your answer where would I add the condition similar to "```where in (this list of CustomerIds)```"

Comment: See my updated answer for your `Where in (` condition.